# Front-end JS and the lack of http/authentication management

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, axios, web-frontend

Last days I was developing an http manager for the front of an app, with a part of authentication. For the context this app is made with Typescript, React-redux, and a back with Java/Springboot.

I wanted to :

- link the typing of the request with the typing of the data returned by the server, like that:

  ```
  request({
     type: 'login', 
     parameters: {
         username, 
         password
     } 
  }).then(response => {
      typeof response.data;
      // for the request type 'login'
      // the data returned is { token: string } 
  })
  ```
- handle the authentication, requests that need it
- handle CRUD requests with simplicity

**The problem, I have to do all the work myself.** I didn't found any library that help me.

I use Axios but it's not a manager like i imagine. 
I know there is an Angular module, HttpClient i think, that seems to respect my need, but it's by definition Angular-oriented. I found RxJS making reactive requests with observables, but I don't think it's what i'm searching.

It's a problematic I encounter pretty often, http requests and authentication are common of most of the web apps. It's obvious that every front dev know this problem.

NodeJS has Passport.js, Java has Spring, etc 
What do we have in the front-end ?

Comment: Have you tried using axios interceptors?

Comment: @charlietfl Yep, for auth and error handling. But we have to make these interceptors ourselves for each project whereas the logic is always the same. My question is not on the side of feasibility but of factorization and consistency.

Comment: Not always the same in apps I work on but creating your own configurable transport class that you can use cross project is what I do